# how do setData in Block magento2?

Tags: magento2

i created function call my block. so i want use getData() i my block 
i tried
`function maxTest($name, $data){
     $name->getLayout()->createBlock('Namespace\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock',[emty_id=>$data])
}`;

after i call `print_r($this->getData());` in `Namespace\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock` it not has. so how do setData() in may function. Many thank.

Answer (score 2):

You have to key the data like so;

```
['data' => ['emty_id' => $data]]
```

Also, i believe you are passing the data in to the wrong parameter. If you look at the definition of createBlock the second argument is the $name. Try doing;

```
$name->getLayout()->createBlock('Namespace\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock', '', ['data' => ['emty_id' => $data]]);
```

Later in the block generation code there is a section that does the following (which is why you have to use "data" as the key in the arguments list);

```
$block->addData(isset($arguments['data']) ? $arguments['data'] : []);
```